# Create a matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this from [Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica) and I want to create it in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)

```
pointers = 
  Table[If[experiment[[i, 1]]^2 + experiment[[i, 2]]^2 > 1, 0, 1], {i,
     1, npoints}];
```

The output is for example {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, for npoints = 10.

I tried this, but it's wrong! (I am learning MATLAB now, I have a little from Mathematica though)

```
assign=experiment(i,1)^2 +experiment(i,2)^2;
if assign>1
    assign=0;
else assign=1;
end
pointers=assign(1:npoints);
```

I also did this which gives output 1, but it's wrong:

```
for i=1:npoints
assign=length(experiment(i,1)^2 +experiment(i,2)^2);
if assign>1
    assign=0;
else assign=1;
end
end
pointers=assign
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you need to index `pointers`, i.e. write

```
pointers(i) = assign;
```

and not call 'length' in the second line.

However, a much easier solution is to write

```
pointers = (experiment(:,1).^2 + experiment(:,2).^2) <= 1
```

With this, you're creating, inside the parentheses, a new array with the result of the sum of squares. This array can then be checked for being smaller or equal 1 (i.e. if it's bigger than 1, the result is 0), returning the result of all the comparison in the array `pointers`.

Comment: @George: Regarding your additional question (which should really be a comment, or an edit of your original question): The logical comparison does all the checking. Comparing an array with a scalar performs the operation on each element of the array. The `IF` command in Mathematica (as well as Excel) allows you to specify the result for the two outcomes. A logical comparison as I do in Matlab can only return 0 or 1, but you can easily manipulate the result so that you can obtain any other value. By the way, if you find the answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: First of all,thanks for your answer.

I wanted to ask ,
With the <=1 in the end you are doing all the check?You don't need to execute an if statement, right?
In which cases we can do things like that? 

Thanks again

Comment: @George: Have a look at the following post http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/ or google for MATLAB and logical indexing.

Comment: @George please use comments for this.

Comment: "....A logical comparison as I do in Matlab can only return 0 or 1, but you can easily manipulate the result so that you can obtain any other value...."   How can i do this?(manipulate it?)For example ,i have "xpoints = Table[RandomReal[], {z1, 1, np1}]",how can i write it in an one line?

Comment: @George: That's not a logical comparison, but you're creating an array of random values, right? In Matlab, you'd run `xpoints = rand(np1,1)` to get a np1-by-1 array of uniform random values between 0 and 1.

Comment: First of all,thanks for your quick answer.Because i am a beginner in programming forgive me for my mistakes.I am trying to understand matlab coding because is a bit different.Yes,the example that i gave you wasn't logical.I meant if we had "if"in the above example,how could we write the expression in one line ,as before?Before,we had values only 0 and 1 .If we have different values ,how we manipulate them?Thanks!

Comment: @George: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you want. I suggest that you put this up as a new question, so that you have the space to explain (for the non-Mathematica people) what kind of behavior you'd like to see.

Comment: I am just telling that previously in one line you did this :"pointers = (experiment(:,1).^2 + experiment(:,2).^2) <= 1  " .This checks if pointers<=1 and then gives 1 or 0 as result.But if i wanted my expression to return other values(not 1 or 0) how could i have done this?

Comment: @George: I just meant that if you wanted to give -1 and 1 as results instead of 1 and 0, you would have manipulated the statement by calling `(0.5-statement)*2`, where `statement` is the inequality.